# Large data insertion issue in hyperledger fabric(test-network v2.4)

Tags: docker, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, large-data, hyperledger-chaincode

We are trying to insert **large data** in by dividing it in chunks, but after inserting approx **200MB** data we receive `"No successful event received"` error.

---

`Test network is running in docker in windows.`

---

Tried to change time-out settings. API sever stops after inserting certain amount of data. Once you restart the server(not the blockchain network), it allows to insert data again.